# Loading new version of update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an internal update site (common) that is being consumed by other parts of application. A lot of times when I build common and try to consume it, I don't get the latest version. I try to clean my workspace, change sequenceNumber in target definition, but what ultimately helps is starting new Eclipse workspace. Is there a better solution to force latest update site version? I do have version="0.0.0" in target definition for common update site.

Comment: Did you try _Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform: Reload..._?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't help

Comment: Is there cache I can purge to force an update?

Comment: How do you build your internal update site? A p2 update site has a timestamp. Is it increased when the update site is updated?

Comment: It does, but when I refresh my target definition, it shows old one. The only thing that helps in starting new workspace, so this tells that cache retrieval doesn't work properly on my machine. I am on Ubuntu, btw.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you use? Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165246/discussion-between-alex-kravets-and-howlger).